# Parse application taking too much time to load when implementing push notifications

Tags: android, push-notification, parse-platform

I am trying to make a simple push notification application where I am using Parse dot com for the back-end and I followed the instructions from several tutorials.

**Problem 1 :** When I define my application id's and client id's, and use that in the manifest, the application just freezes and gives an ANR.

This is a basic setup I am using for defining the keys :

```
public class EntryPoint extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();

        ParseObject.registerSubclass(ParseModel.class);

        // Parse.initialize(this, "YOUR_PARSE_APPLICATION_ID",
        // "YOUR_PARSE_CLIENT_KEY");
        Parse.initialize(this, "your_app_id",
                "your_client_id");

        PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);

        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();


        String droidID = Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),Secure.ANDROID_ID);         

        ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();    

        installation.put("UniqueId",droidID);

        installation.saveInBackground();

    }

}
```

And this is the **manifest** :

```
<application
        android:name="com.mike.EntryPoint"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity> 

<application
```

**NOTE :** Other receivers and services are defined already in the manifest.

When I remove **android:name="com.mike.EntryPoint"** from the application tag, the app runs fine and no issues with it. But in order to use push notifications, we do need the tag names in the application tag.

Is there something I am missing or is there a other work around using push notifications using parse backend ?

If it is, I will really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance .. :)

Comment: May be related to this: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/507987575990925/ as a test try removing all saves of ParseInstallation from your Applications onCreate()

Comment: That's right .. this is a known bug in Parse and not sure how will that be fixed.